# Create C# SOAP API Consumable by other Languages

Tags: c#, api, soap, service, wsdl

I've been trying to find a tutorial on here, MSDN, and Google on how to implement my own SOAP API. I have an application written in C# that I want to be consumable by PHP so that calls from the web can interact with the application. How do I generate and tie a WSDL file to my application so that it can be communicated with over SOAP calls? Any suggestions?

Comment: Create an ASP.NET Web Service. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/94043/SOAP-Web-Services-Create-Once-Consume-Everywhere

Comment: Typed "call WCF from PHP" on Google.. first result : http://www.rizalalmashoor.com/blog/calling-a-wcf-service-from-php/

Answer (score 3):

I think for this you just need to create WCF service in .net that will allow you to consume server from any language.

Comment: Awesome. One more question. Once I create the project in WCF, how do I tie the service to my application to where the WCF service calls methods in my application? Would I just add a service reference like I normally would if I were going to consume any other service? The reason I ask, and read carefully, is because "consuming" web services writes "client" information to be able to consume a service and use methods of that service in C#. I need to be able to instead consume the service from php and have it call methods in the C# application (which by the way is a WinForms project).

Comment: @user1377460 - you have to expose service at some address which is known as endpoint than you need to point to that endpoint to consume webservice in your application..you can find about this on google easily...

Comment: I understand how it works because I have already integrated Magento with Quickbooks usings SOAP. What I'm asking is how does the WCF service call methods in my WinForms C# application from PHP. I don't know how else to word the question. I know in PHP that I'm going to use SoapClient to connect to my endpoint and call methods on it, what I'm asking is, how does the SOAP service then call those methods in my WinForms application? PHP -> WCF SOAP Service -> WinForms C# Application. I know the pathway, just don't know how to make the WCF service call methods in my Winforms application.

Answer (score 0):

Create an ASP.Net Web Services .wsdl file to communicate with the various applications. Host the Web Service on windows IIS server and configure the ports accordingly, then you can access the endpoints to whcih ever application you are using, using the address and the web method name.